# Sencha Touch Chart: how can I handle TAP on a Bar column?

Tags: sencha-charts

I've successfully implemented a Bar chart; now I would like to trap the user touch. I've tried by using Interactions but cannot get the clicked item.

Answer (score 1):

you have to create your own function in `touch-charts-debug.js` and refer that function in interactions instead of `type:'iteminfo'` in your chart.

I have tried with this option it works fine for me As am able to show drill down chart on tapping the bar.

Answer (score 0):

The sencha-charts that I can find online say they use HTML5. If that is the case then you should be able to capture it like a mouse click except using touchstart, touchmove, touchend, and more.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/touch.html#toc-events

Ah, just read. They also use jqtouch:

http://jqtouch.com/

according to http://www.sencha.com/blog/introducing-sencha-touch-html5-framework-for-mobile/

Here are some examples for getting an event with jqtouch:

http://code.google.com/p/jqtouch/wiki/CallbackEvents